# Weird NullPointerException on android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.initializeTheme()

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

There are 5% users report this issue(total users are about 10s of Million), but I just can't find a clue.
It happens while launching the app right after upgrading to a new version.
The stack trace doesn't show any signs of the codes I wrote in the program, just like below.
Could anybody help? hint me.

```
null 
android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.initializeTheme()
ContextThemeWrapper.java:100
android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.setTheme() ContextThemeWrapper.java:51
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity() ActivityThread.java:2144
android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity() ActivityThread.java:2211
android.app.ActivityThread.access$600() ActivityThread.java:149
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage() ActivityThread.java:1300
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage() Handler.java:99
android.os.Looper.loop()Looper.java:153
android.app.ActivityThread.main() ActivityThread.java:5108
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative() Method.java:-2
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke() Method.java:511
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() ZygoteInit.java:989
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main() ZygoteInit.java:747
dalvik.system.NativeStart.main()
NativeStart.java:-2
```

Comment: It seems like it only happens in unknown/low end phone.

Comment: Had this one too, while testing a finished app on a Sony Xperia M (Android 4.3). I recompiled and it mystically vanished. The only thing I noticed is, that the upload/installation of the app from Android Studio to the device took very long.